# Colons as divider with Rails Route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, url, routes

I would like to use colons as divider in my rails route url instead of forward slashes. Is it possible to do the this?

---

I'm after something like the following

```
match '*page_path/:title ":" *section_path ":" :section_title' => 'pages#show'
```

so for the url `food/fruit/apples:cooking:pie:apple_pie` would return the parameters:

```
:page_path = "food/fruit"
:title = "apples"
:section_path = "cooking:pie"
:section_title = "apple_pie"
```

---

Is this possible in rails?

Comment: what is wrong with forward slashes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach :

```
match 'food/fruit/:id' => 'pages#show' # add constraints on id if you need

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.from_param( param )
    title, section_path, section_title = extract_from_param( param ) 
    # your find logic here, ex: find_by_title_and_section_path_and_section_title...
  end

  def to_param
    # build your param string here, 
    # ex: "#{title}:#{section_path}:#{section_title}" 
    # Beware ! now all your urls relative to this resource
    # will use this method instead of #id. 
    # The generated param should be unique, of course.
  end

  private

  def self.extract_from_param( param )
    # extract tokens from params here
  end
end
```

then in your controller:

```
 @recipe = Recipe.from_param( params[:id] )
```

note that the use of use the built-in [to_param](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) method is optionnal.